# Change dimensions of images from Twitch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, ejs

I'm making a request to the Twitch API to get a list of top games and display their box art, but the image will only show if I change the `width` and the `height` value in the provided link. How can I change these value in ejs or should I change the values before I provide the context?

```
<% data.forEach(game => { %>

      <img src= <%= game.box_art_url %> alt="">
   
    <%})%>
```

Example API response

```
        {
            "id": "21779",
            "name": "League of Legends",
            "box_art_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ejs` replace `{width}` and `{height}` with your own dimensions - example:

```
<% data.forEach(game => { %>

      <img src= <%= game.box_art_url.replace('{width}', '138').replace('{height}', '190') %> alt="">

<%})%>
```

This will output:

```
<img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/League%20of%20Legends-138x190.jpg" alt="">
```